# Función nunca utilizada en c++

Tags: c++

tengo mi código pero me da error, no me compila, pero el IDE no me marca errores Solo me da warning que me dice que nunca use las funciones, cosa que en el main las tengo invocadas, el IDE y me las marca como grises las funciones de (pedir datos y mostrar) al declararlas, pero no entiendo porque no me funcionan, incluso me da un mensaje que es este: ndefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"pedirDatos(int, Carros)", referenced from:
_main in main.cpp.o
"mostrar(Carros, int)", referenced from:
_main in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

pido ayuda, ya intenté de todo, muchas gracias

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct Carros{
    string placa;
    string marca;


};
int cantidad();
void mostrar(Carros,int);
void pedirDatos(int, Carros);


int main() {
    int n=0;
    Carros *autos=NULL;
    n=cantidad();
    autos = new Carros[n];
    mostrar(*autos,n);
    pedirDatos(n,*autos);

    return 0;
}

int cantidad(){
    int cantidad;
    cout<<"Cantidad de autos a ingresar: "<<endl;
    cin>>cantidad;
    return cantidad;
}
void pedirDatos(int n, Carros *autos){
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        cout<<"Digite la placa del auto "<<i+1<<":"<<endl;
        cin>>autos->placa;
        cout<<"Digite la marca del auto "<<i+1<<": "<<endl;
        cin>>autos->marca;

    }
}
void mostrar(Carros *autos,int n){
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        cout<<"La placa del auto "<<i+1<<" es:"<<endl;
        cout<<autos->placa<<endl;
        cout<<"La marca del auto "<<i+1<<" es: "<<endl;
        cout<<autos->marca<<endl;
        cout<<"El año del auto "<<i+1<< "es :"<<endl;
       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ tiene algo llamado sobrecarga de funciones. Eso significa que puedes tener varias funciones que se llaman igual, pero tienen diferentes tipos y cantidades de parámetros. Por ejemplo:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
 
void function(int n)
{
    std::cout << "function(int " << n << ");\n";
}
 
void function(double d)
{
    std::cout << "function(double " << d << ");\n";
}
 
int main()
{
    function(3);
    function(2.718);
}
```

Te da como resultado:

```
function(int 3);
function(double 2.718);
```

---

Ahora fíjate en tu código. Las firmas de las funciones cuando las declaras son:

```cpp
void mostrar(Carros, int);
void pedirDatos(int, Carros);
```

Y la firma de las funciones cuando las implementas es:

```cpp
void mostrar(Carros *, int);
void pedirDatos(int, Carros *);
```

Te darás cuenta que estas son diferentes. En las primeras usas simplemente `Carros`, y en las segundas usas punteros a `Carros`. La solución tendría que ser sencilla, coloca también punteros a `Carros` donde declaras las funciones.